# Average Value Based on Date in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How to get average from `value` based on corresponding dates in `date`? And how to extend it for the rest of dataframe?

```
| value | date      |
| ----- | ----------
| 10    | 2004-10-03|
| 13    | 2004-10-03|
| 14    | 2004-10-03|
| 5     | 2004-10-03|
| 9     | 2004-10-03|
| 11    | 2004-11-03|
| 5     | 2004-11-03|
| 18    | 2004-11-03|
| 40    | 2004-11-03|
| 5     | 2004-11-03|
```

For `2004-10-03` it shoult return `10.2`

For `2004-11-03` it shoult return `15.8`

Comment: `df.groupby('date').mean()` ? [`groupby mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `groupby`:

```
df.groupby("date")["value"].mean()
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi Please follow the following code :-

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Date': ['2004-10-03', '2004-10-03', '2004-10-03', '2004-10-03','2004-10-03','2004-11-03', '2004-11-03', '2004-11-03', '2004-11-03','2004-11-03'], 
        'Value': [10,13,14,5,9,11,5,18,40,5]}  

df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
df.groupby(['Date'])['Value'].mean()
```